# JMeter getting hanging in GUI mode

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm having problem with jmeter while running the test plan. Suddenly my Jmeter starts hanging and appears as a black screen in GUI mode. I was running recording controller with multiple thread groups (4 thread groups). Each thread group with 25 users.

I'm using Jmeter 2.11 (current version). I'm not sure whether it is due to overload or some other reason.

Regards
Nayasoft

Comment: Have you tried contacting support or filing an issue on their forums or bug tracker? With this specific of an issue, you may have better luck there.

Comment: How long you have been running the test? What is the load/user count?

Comment: Running 4 threads in the test plan. Each threads with 25 users.

Answer (score 3):

Don't ever use GUI mode for load test. Run JMeter [in command-line non-GUI mode as follows](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/testresults.jtl
```

Also if you have any listeners in your test plan - disable or remove them as well. After test execution you should be able to open `testresults.jtl` file with the listener of your choice and analyze results, but don't use them during load test.

Make sure that you following Performance Checklist and other recommendations from [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) guide

Answer (score 0):

You have run out of JMeter/JVM memory.  You can increase in with environment variables, command line options when you start jmeter, or change some values in jmeter.properties

This page describes how to start jmeter with more memory.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html

One easy way is to set the environment variable before running jmeter:

```
set JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
```

This will allow your tests to run longer before running out of memory, but if you store results in memory (for instance using View Results Tree listener), you will still run out eventually.  For long running tests, or accurate measurement of short running tests, it is better to run in non-GUI mode, and save results to file, instead of memory.

Graphs can still be generated after the run from the saved results using jmeter utilities.